# Finding extremums of Abs[complex function]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

We have a function same as

```
f[x_]=Cos[x] Cos[2 x] + I Sin[x] Sin[2 x]
```

The final objective is to find all extremums of Abs[f[x]] in [0,2 pi]. But in the first step there is a problem because `Abs[x + I y] != Sqrt[x^2+y^2]` except `x` and `y` be numeric. Also, in any trick Function same as: `FindMaximum` could not help for finding **ALL** of extremums. How can I find `MAX` and `MIN` of `Abs[f[x]]` with their values of x and f[x]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem can be completely solved symbolically using the standard methods.
Here we go.

The function in question is given by

```
f[x_] := Cos[x] Cos[2 x] + I Sin[x] Sin[2 x]
```

The square of the absolute value for real x is then

```
fa[x_] = ComplexExpand[f[x]*Conjugate[f[x]]] // Simplify

(*
Out[94]= Cos[x]^2 (2 - 2 Cos[2 x] + Cos[4 x])
*)
```

The extrema of `Abs[f[x]]` are in the same location as those of `fa[x].`

Looking for zeroes in the derivative gives

```
eq = D[fa[x], x] == 0 // Simplify

(*
Out[98]= Cos[x] (4 Sin[x] - 3 Sin[3 x] + 3 Sin[5 x]) == 0
*)

sol = Solve[eq && 0 <= x <= 2 \[Pi], x]

(*
Out[131]= {{x -> 0}, {x -> \[Pi]/2}, {x -> \[Pi]}, {x -> (3 \[Pi])/2}, {x -> 
   2 \[Pi]}, {x -> 
   2 \[Pi] - 
    2 ArcTan[Sqrt[Root[5 - 76 #1 + 222 #1^2 - 76 #1^3 + 5 #1^4 &, 1]]]}, {x ->
    2 ArcTan[Sqrt[Root[5 - 76 #1 + 222 #1^2 - 76 #1^3 + 5 #1^4 &, 1]]]}, {x ->
    2 \[Pi] - 
    2 ArcTan[Sqrt[Root[5 - 76 #1 + 222 #1^2 - 76 #1^3 + 5 #1^4 &, 2]]]}, {x ->
    2 ArcTan[Sqrt[Root[5 - 76 #1 + 222 #1^2 - 76 #1^3 + 5 #1^4 &, 2]]]}, {x ->
    2 \[Pi] - 
    2 ArcTan[Sqrt[Root[5 - 76 #1 + 222 #1^2 - 76 #1^3 + 5 #1^4 &, 3]]]}, {x ->
    2 ArcTan[Sqrt[Root[5 - 76 #1 + 222 #1^2 - 76 #1^3 + 5 #1^4 &, 3]]]}, {x ->
    2 \[Pi] - 
    2 ArcTan[Sqrt[Root[5 - 76 #1 + 222 #1^2 - 76 #1^3 + 5 #1^4 &, 4]]]}, {x ->
    2 ArcTan[Sqrt[Root[5 - 76 #1 + 222 #1^2 - 76 #1^3 + 5 #1^4 &, 4]]]}}
*)

Length[sol]

(* Out[106]= 13 *)
```

Hence we have found 13 solutions. The first five are simple expressions. 
The others ones can be simplified, but I have found no dierect way of simplify the `Root[]` expressions.

But I discovered by accident that the following works out fine: solving eq without the interval restrictions, chosing the appropriate integer parameters `C[i]` and and imposing the interval restriction afterwards gives

```
sol1 = Solve[eq, x];
sol1x = Select[
  Union[x /. sol1 /. C[1] -> 0, x /. sol1 /. C[1] -> 1], 0 <= # <= 2 \[Pi] &]

(*
Out[171]= {0, \[Pi]/2, \[Pi], (3 \[Pi])/2, 
 2 \[Pi], \[Pi] - ArcTan[Sqrt[(6 - Sqrt[6])/(6 + Sqrt[6])]], 
 2 \[Pi] - ArcTan[Sqrt[(6 - Sqrt[6])/(6 + Sqrt[6])]], 
 ArcTan[Sqrt[(6 - Sqrt[6])/(6 + Sqrt[6])]], \[Pi] + 
  ArcTan[Sqrt[(6 - Sqrt[6])/(6 + Sqrt[6])]], \[Pi] - 
  ArcTan[Sqrt[(6 + Sqrt[6])/(6 - Sqrt[6])]], 
 2 \[Pi] - ArcTan[Sqrt[(6 + Sqrt[6])/(6 - Sqrt[6])]], 
 ArcTan[Sqrt[(6 + Sqrt[6])/(6 - Sqrt[6])]], \[Pi] + 
  ArcTan[Sqrt[(6 + Sqrt[6])/(6 - Sqrt[6])]]}
*)
```

We recover 13 Solutions which are now explicit expressions.

```
Length[sol1x]

(* Out[173]= 13 *)
```

All are in the requested interval

```
sol1x/(2 \[Pi]) // N

(*
Out[174]= {0., 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1., 0.408465, 0.908465, 0.0915349, 0.591535, 0.341535, 0.841535, 0.158465, 0.658465}
*)
```

Now here is the explicit solution of the problem: all extrema and their locations:

```
txfa = Table[{sol1x[[i]], fa[sol1x[[i]]]}, {i, 1, Length[sol1x]}] // Simplify

(*
Out[165]= {{0, 1}, {\[Pi]/2, 0}, {\[Pi], 1}, {(3 \[Pi])/2, 0}, {2 \[Pi], 
  1}, {\[Pi] - ArcTan[Sqrt[1/5 (7 - 2 Sqrt[6])]], 
  1/12 (6 + Sqrt[6]) (2 - 2 Cos[2 ArcTan[Sqrt[1/5 (7 - 2 Sqrt[6])]]] + 
     Cos[4 ArcTan[Sqrt[1/5 (7 - 2 Sqrt[6])]]])}, {2 \[Pi] - 
   ArcTan[Sqrt[1/5 (7 - 2 Sqrt[6])]], 
  1/12 (6 + Sqrt[6]) (2 - 2 Cos[2 ArcTan[Sqrt[1/5 (7 - 2 Sqrt[6])]]] + 
     Cos[4 ArcTan[Sqrt[1/5 (7 - 2 Sqrt[6])]]])}, {ArcTan[Sqrt[
   1/5 (7 - 2 Sqrt[6])]], 
  1/12 (6 + Sqrt[6]) (2 - 2 Cos[2 ArcTan[Sqrt[1/5 (7 - 2 Sqrt[6])]]] + 
     Cos[4 ArcTan[Sqrt[1/5 (7 - 2 Sqrt[6])]]])}, {\[Pi] + 
   ArcTan[Sqrt[1/5 (7 - 2 Sqrt[6])]], 
  1/12 (6 + Sqrt[6]) (2 - 2 Cos[2 ArcTan[Sqrt[1/5 (7 - 2 Sqrt[6])]]] + 
     Cos[4 ArcTan[Sqrt[1/5 (7 - 2 Sqrt[6])]]])}, {\[Pi] - 
   ArcTan[Sqrt[1/5 (7 + 2 Sqrt[6])]], -(1/
    12) (-6 + Sqrt[6]) (2 - 2 Cos[2 ArcTan[Sqrt[1/5 (7 + 2 Sqrt[6])]]] + 
     Cos[4 ArcTan[Sqrt[1/5 (7 + 2 Sqrt[6])]]])}, {2 \[Pi] - 
   ArcTan[Sqrt[1/5 (7 + 2 Sqrt[6])]], -(1/
    12) (-6 + Sqrt[6]) (2 - 2 Cos[2 ArcTan[Sqrt[1/5 (7 + 2 Sqrt[6])]]] + 
     Cos[4 ArcTan[Sqrt[1/5 (7 + 2 Sqrt[6])]]])}, {ArcTan[Sqrt[
   1/5 (7 + 2 Sqrt[6])]], -(1/
    12) (-6 + Sqrt[6]) (2 - 2 Cos[2 ArcTan[Sqrt[1/5 (7 + 2 Sqrt[6])]]] + 
     Cos[4 ArcTan[Sqrt[1/5 (7 + 2 Sqrt[6])]]])}, {\[Pi] + 
   ArcTan[Sqrt[1/5 (7 + 2 Sqrt[6])]], -(1/
    12) (-6 + Sqrt[6]) (2 - 2 Cos[2 ArcTan[Sqrt[1/5 (7 + 2 Sqrt[6])]]] + 
     Cos[4 ArcTan[Sqrt[1/5 (7 + 2 Sqrt[6])]]])}}
*)

txfa // N // Sort

(*
Out[175]= {{0., 1.}, {0.575131, 0.363917}, {0.995665, 0.636083}, {1.5708, 0.}, {2.14593, 0.636083}, {2.56646, 0.363917}, {3.14159, 1.}, {3.71672, 
  0.363917}, {4.13726, 0.636083}, {4.71239, 0.}, {5.28752, 
  0.636083}, {5.70805, 0.363917}, {6.28319, 1.}}
*)
```

Finally, let's have a look at the function and its extrema

```
p1 = Plot[fa[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}];
p2 = ListPlot[txfa, PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[1, 0, 0], PointSize[0.02]}];

Show[p1, p2]
(* 150917_Plot_Extrema.jpg *)
```

[image]

Comment: Nicely done, as usual... +1

Comment: @Dr.Wolfgang Hintze, Besides so much thanks, I think you mean of _tt_ as txfa//N! because it is not defined before plot. Also can you translate a bit little this line: Select[
  Union[x /. sol1 /. C[1] -> 0, x /. sol1 /. C[1] -> 1], 0 <= # <= 2 \[Pi] &].

Comment: @ mr.0093: thank you for pointing out the tt->txfa error. It is correct now. As for the stuff with  Union and C[i], please do the steps I have described in the text. You will easily find out how it works. If not, please tell me.

Comment: I think this line essential because of existing ArcTan and some functions same as that, because each theta+2pi or something else theta+pi can be a solution, you check that it was in [0,2pi], but I find a problem that this doesn't work correctly and a correct answer goes away, If fa[x]=1 + 3 Cos[2 x]) Sin[2 x], you can see this method removes x -> 5.32787 and t -> 6.28319 (that is 2pi itself)!!!!

Comment: @ mr.0093 the constants C[i] are arbitrariy within the domain of integers - as Solve tells you. So, in order to confine your solution to a certain interval, you have to fix them properly. This can be done one by one by hand or, as I did here, as a suitable collection put together with Union[].

Comment: really a very good solution!

Answer (score 5):

I sometimes have a similar problem and a rather "rough" workaround. First make a plot of the function - omitting the output:

```
p = Plot[Norm@f[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}];
```

then extract the line segments

```
data = Cases[p, Line[{x__}] :> x, \[Infinity]];
```

then find the peaks

```
max = FindPeaks[#[[2]] & /@ data]
```

finally plot the result(s):

```
Show[p, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[data[[First /@ max]]]}]
```

O.K. a bit "brute force" and not so elegant, but working. You´ll get this plot and can process the data further on.
[image: Plot of norm with maxima]

Comment: @ mgamer : very elegant. I recently did something similar (i.e. going into the structure of the output of Plot[]) when trying to find find jumps in a given function.

Comment: @mgamer, How can I determine the minimums, because I could not find a function same as FindPeaks for minimums!

Comment: @mr.0093: Just like in optimization take the max of -f :-)